# Ansible conditionals on list variables passed into a role

Tags: ansible

I have following ansible code

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - { role: roleone }
    - { role: roletwo, myvariable : ["var1","var2"] }
```

I need to set this list variable based on conditional. 
Below is what I have tried, although it does not work:

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - { role: roleone }
    - { role: roletwo, myvariable : ["foo1","foo2"], when: init=="true", myvariable : ["bar1","bar2"], when: init == "false" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by using following code:

```
---
- hosts: all
  roles:
  - { role: roleone }
  - { role: roletwo, myvariable: "{{ ['var1','var2'] if (init == "true") else ['bar1','bar2'] }}" }
```